# How to reduce the size of Google PHP library?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

The size of Google php API Library is very large. I just want to send an email with the library. How can I reduce its size?

Answer (score 12):

To reduce the vendor library size,
`google/apiclient` offers a configuration on composer.json to run a cleanup script post-update.

This way you can specify only your required apis,
to reduce storage size on production.
Especially if you are going to use it on tighter storage requirement environment, like serverless architecture.

Reference: https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient

> The required apis specified under "google/apiclient-services", please refer to https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/main/src

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
    "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "Drive",
            "YouTube"
        ]
    }
}
```

for no services at all (for instance you're only using the API to [verify the integrity of a JWT ID token](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library)) the `extra.google/apiclient-services` array/list needs to contain an empty string

```
"extra": {
    "google/apiclient-services": [ "" ]
}
```

You may want remove the entire apiservices folder first, and then do a composer update, if you already installed a full set of api.

```
$ rm -r vendor/google/apiclient-services
$ composer update
```

Comment: Where can I find the correct names of the packages that I need ?

Comment: @btx For the package name list that is generated, please refer to https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/main/src

Answer (score 1):

The reason the library is large is that it contains all of the classes for all of the Google Discovery api's i think there are around 120 of them.

The only way i know of to reduce the size is to remove all of the APIs you dont need.  check the `Google/Service` directory.  Delete the apis you are not planning on using.

Leave everything else.

There is also the option of

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Comment: what about `bin\  cache\  composer\  dealerdirect\  doctrine\  firebase\  justinrainbow\  league\  monolog\  myclabs\  phpcompatibility\  phpdocumentor\  phpseclib\  phpspec\  phpunit\  psr\  ralouphie\  sebastian\  seld\  squizlabs\  symfony\  webmozart\` can I get rid of these?

Comment: try if it breaks put them back?

Comment: `composer install --no-dev` helped a lot, I didn't know about this option